.NET MAUI: The tab switching functionality is not working properly on the iOS platform
We have three tabs in our application. Initially, switching from the first tab to the third tab works fine. However, when trying to switch back from the third tab to the first tab, it does not work as expected. Instead, it navigates from the third tab to the second tab, and only then allows switching to the first tab. This issue occurs only on the iOS platform and works fine on Android Platform.
The first tab is a CarouselPage, while the other two tabs are ContentView pages. After logging into the app, the three tabs appear. From the CarouselPage, I am using WeakReferenceMessenger to handle the swiping between tabs starting from the first page. Below is a sample code snippet for sending the WeakReferenceMessenger:
<CarouselView 
    x:Name="carouselView"
    CurrentItemChanged="OnCurrentItemChanged"
    Loop="False">
    <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type ContentView}">
            <control:HomePage/>
            <control:FriendsPage/>
            <control:HistoryPage/>
        </x:Array>
    </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentView Content="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>

void OnCurrentItemChanged(object sender, CurrentItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Position:>>" + carouselView.Position);
        int index = carouselView.Position;
        AddWeakReferenceMessenger(index);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>" + ex);
    }
}

private void AddWeakReferenceMessenger(int index)
{
    try
    {
        if (index == 0)
        {
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new HomeTabChangeMessage("home_tab"));
        }
        else if (index == 1)
        {
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new HomeTabChangeMessage("friends_tab"));
        }
        else if (index == 2)
        {
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new HomeTabChangeMessage("history_tab"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>" + ex);
    }
}

This WeakReferenceMessenger is registered to each tab. Below is a sample code snippet for third tab to subscribe to the message.
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<HomeTabChangeMessage>(this, async (r, m) =>
{
    if (m.Value == "history_tab")
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("isHistoryLoaded:>>" + Utility.isHistoryLoaded);
        if (!Utility.isHistoryLoaded)
        {
            UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("");
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25));
            Utility.isHistoryLoaded = true;
            await Task.Run(async () => await SetHistoryListItems());
        }
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Unregister<HomeTabChangeMessage>(this);
    }
});

Below is a sample code snippet for sending the WeakReferenceMessenger for switching from third tab to first tab:
public void ShowHome(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new TabSelectionMessage("child-0"));
}

Below is a sample code snippet for first tab to subscribe to the message.
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<TabSelectionMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
{
    try
    {
        string[] childArray = m.Value.Split("-");
        if (childArray[0] == "child")
        {
            carouselView.ScrollTo(Int32.Parse(childArray[1]));
            AddWeakReferenceMessenger(Int32.Parse(childArray[1]));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("TabSelectionException>>:" + ex);
    }
});

Can u please provide a solution for this issue?

What is the version of the iOS device you are running this project on? Does this problem also occur on other versions?

@Shuowen He-MSFT This issue occurs on the iOS simulator for both iPhone and iPad.

he asked for the version you are using

@Shuowen He-MSFT The iOS version is 16.4

Actually I don't understand your project structure. If you use the tab structure of Shell, each tab should be a page. Can you add more code about the project structure? For example, AppShell.xaml，this would be helpful for me to reproduce your problem.
